# Can't find what is wrong with this matrix proof

Tags: linear-algebra

I can't seem to understand where this might go wrong. Note: the notation $A^{-T}$ means $(A^{-1})^T$ (or $(A^T)^{-1}$).

$$P = (A(A^TA))^{-1}A^T=A(A)^{-1}(A)^{-T}A^T=(AA^{-1})(AA^{-1})^T=II^T=I$$

Comment: What do you mean by $(A)^-T$? (I've modified the rest of the formula, but I don't understand what you mean here)

Comment: The brackets don't match with the way you are expanding them. That very first inverse is outside the second bracket, but you seem to be treating it as if it is between the inside and outside brackets.

Comment: Sorry about the exponent issue. To clarify, (A)-T means A^-T or in other words, A raised to the exponent of -T.

Comment: I guess $A^{-T}$ is $(A^{-1})^T=(A^T)^{-1}$.

Comment: It might go wrong if A is not invertible.

Comment: Can you please clarify how you got the first step?

Comment: $(AA^TA)^{-1}$ equals $A^{-1}A^{-T}A^{-1}$, not $AA^{-1}A^{-T}$. That's the issue. I don't see why so many people are hawking about clarifying what $A^{-T}$ means (not uncommon notation) and that $A$ is invertible (of course that's assumed).

Answer (score 1):

In a case like this, you might just pick a simple matrix $A$ and try it out:

With $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

you get

$(AA^TA)^{-1}A^T=\begin{bmatrix}-1&-3 \\1&2\end{bmatrix}$

whereas the rest of the expressions are trivially the identity $I_2$.

So, your problem lies in the first supposed equality.

Apparently you're not keeping correct track of the order of multiplication.

One can say
$(AA^TA)^{-1}A^T=A^{-1}(A^T)^{-1}A^{-1}A^T$ but there's nowhere apparently to go from there.

One might erroneously draw the conclusion that the inverse is being distributed to the terms, but actually it's being distributed and the *order is being reversed*. That is: $(ABC)^{-1}=C^{-1}B^{-1}A^{-1}$.